# get each child('id') into array or string

Tags: jquery, arrays, each, children

I need to create a comma separated value for a hidden input created from a series of div id's

```
<div id="main">
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
<div id="C"></div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="children"/>
```

I want to use jquery but having trouble with the function

```
    function update_input(main){
        var array = new Array();

           $('#'+main).children('id').each(function(){
                 array.push($(this).attr('div'));  
           });         

        input_value = array.toString();
        $('#children').val(input_value);
    }
```

This is not right

Comment: We know it's not right. What *exactly* do you know is wrong with it? Are there any *specific* errors?

Comment: Check your quotes and brackets! Spoiler: minus quote after main plus right parenthesis after id quote plus right parenthesis after first }

Comment: Syntax highlighting is exactly for what you can see. It tells you there's something wrong.

Comment: sorry, copy and paste, then change certain variables for simplicity. fixed... alert(input_value); is empty

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
    $('div','#main').each(function(){
      array.push($(this).attr('id')); 
    });
```

Comment: I am using this one. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 11):

You could use `map` -

```
​var arr = $("#main > div").map(function() {return this.id});
$('#children').val(arr.get().join(","));
```

The code above relies on your HTML being changed to -

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="A"></div>
    <div id="B"></div>
    <div id="C"></div>
</div>​
```

The `map` function will return a jQuery object containing the ids of each div contained within the 'main' div. You can the call the `get()` function to turn the object returned by the `map` function into a Javascript array, and then use the `join` function to return a comma delimited string.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/8tZXH/1

Answer (score 3):

```
var ids = $('#main > td').map(function(){
                 return this.id
           }).toArray(); 

$('#children').val(ids);
```

Comment: @ThiefMaster: All my new posts are now CW. I'm just liking it better that way for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `children('div')`, not `children('id')`